# bootstrap: allow scrolling below certain width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

first time to ask a question here. Tried to do homework already by searching for "bootstrap force scrolling" and the likes.

I am learning to use twitter bootstrap designing a responsive view specific for mobile at the moment, so I would just like the page to scroll horizontally when width is below 1024px. I tried looking at standard bootstrap-responsive.css and removed all the blocks for max-width=980px / (min-width:768) and (max-width:979) but my div still got wrapped into multiple lines instead of scrolling. am i doing something stupid?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the bootstrap CSS directly is a bad idea - it is complied from [LESS](http://lesscss.org), a CSS preprocessor. You have two choices:

1. Use the handy Bootstrap [customize page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) and choose which responsive sizes you would like to include. In your case, you would probably want to uncheck "Narrow tablets and below" and "Tablets to desktops".
2. Download Bootstrap in LESS form, change the responsive widths to exactly what you want, and compile into CSS.